# Images not loading Django website

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

Images on my django website are not loading for some reason

This is my **models.py**

```
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True)
```

This is my **settings.py** lines

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
if DEBUG:
     STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/static-only')
     MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
     STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/static'),
     )
```

This is my **views.py**

```
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.published()
    template_name = "index.html"
    paginate_by = 5
```

In **url.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In **index.html** i did this

```
<img class="img-rounded" src = "{{object.thumbnail.url}}"/>
```

**pip freeze**

```
Django==1.11.2
django-ckeditor==5.2.2
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-markdown==0.8.4
django-pagedown==0.1.3
Markdown==2.6.8
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.1.1
```

The Images are getting saved in the static/media/images directory 
But the images are not loading in the web page...

When i try to right-click and view the image It shows this error [SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufk3w.png)

Other objects are working perfectly.. Only the images aren't loading

Comment: Are you in debug mode?

Comment: Yes I am in debug mode

Comment: How you are adding the images? admin?

Comment: Yes from the django admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is fixed, (Got assistance from a facebook group)

The issue was a url pattern in the views.py 
The screen shot that I put had a line

**Raised by : blog.views.Blogdetail**

Apparently i had a urlpattern

```
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='entry_detail'),
```

My pattern for blog detail view has match \S+ - so any string of characters that has no spaces in
Which will match pretty much any pattern that hasn't matched previously and any other url pattern which are below this particular url will not be accessed

Changed the url pattern to the following and I was good to go

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(),name='entry_detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the media url in the src:

```
<img class="img-rounded" src = "{{object.thumbnail.url}}"/>
```

should be:

```
<img class="img-rounded" src = "{{MEDIA_URL}}{{object.thumbnail.url}}"/>
```

or something similar

```
<img class="img-rounded" src = "/static/media/uploads/{{object.thumbnail.url}}"/>
```

Comment: Still have the same problem

Comment: Not Found: /media/Knowledge_is_power_by_Pcbots.blogspot.com.png
[29/Jun/2017 14:37:45] "GET /media/Knowledge_is_power_by_Pcbots.blogspot.com.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1807

This is the error in commandline

Comment: you are uploading the image to /images ? that is missing in the url. so try src='images/{{object.thumbnail.url}}'

Answer (score 0):

*settings.py:*

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

in this model you can see Overwrite of exist IMG, return img as base string:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=700):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('defaultfolder', instance.phone, filename)


class ImgModel(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage(),
           upload_to=phone_upload_location,
           null=True,
           blank=True,
           max_length=700)

    def image_to_base64(self, model_picture_path):
        if model_picture_path:
            try:
                with open(model_picture_path.path, "rb") as imageFile:
                    str = b64encode(imageFile.read())
                return "data:image/jpg;base64,%s" % str.decode()

            except IOError:
                return model_picture_path.url
        else:
            return None
```

.html

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}foo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and I tried lot of things but imges wont load then I tried out a simple trick but this did the job. What I did was, in my settings.py file, I included the STATIC_DIR varaible just after BASE_DIR. Below is my settings.py file

**Settings.py**

```
#Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

#Other content

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    STATIC_DIR,
)
```

Check this out maybe this will help!

Answer (score 0):

How to fix images answer is

mention above index.html 
{% static 'travello/images/' as baseUrl %}
path

then

Comment: and then? I think you are missing part of your answer here~